# Cálculo de fatorial sem finalizar o programa

Tags: c, fatorial

Como eu faria para esse algoritmo não encerrar o programa e permitir que eu escreva outros números para calcular o fatorial? já tentei colocar um `while`, ou `do while`, mas de nenhuma forma funciona, pois passa pelo `for` e o programa logo encerra..

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char resp;
int cont, num;
long fat=1;

main()
{
    printf("Digite um numero para calcular o fatorial: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for(cont=num;cont>1;cont--){
        fat = fat*cont;
    }
    printf("%d! = %d", num, fat);

    printf("\nContinuar [S/N]? ");
    scanf("%c", &resp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O fluxo do seu programa é extremamente semelhante ao apresentado na pergunta que sugeri como duplicata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisava apenas dar um espaço no `"%c"` do `scanf("%c", &resp);` deixando essa forma: `scanf(" %c", &resp);`, com o `do while`, a função ficou dessa forma:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



main()
{
  char resp;
    do{
      long fat=1;
      int cont, num;
    printf("Digite um numero para calcular o fatorial: ");

    scanf("%d", &num);

    for(cont=num;cont>1;cont--){
        fat = fat*cont;
    }
    printf("%d! = %d", num, fat);

    printf("\nContinuar [S/N]? ");
    scanf(" %c", &resp);
    }while(resp != 'N');

    return 0;
}
```

Esse espaço é o suficiente para o  `scanf()` entender que é uma nova entrada. Também poderia-mos utilizar a função `fflush(stdin)` para evitar esse problema (recomendo você ler sobre ele).  Um abraço!

Comment: Funcionou o loop, o problema agora está quando eu digito o próximo número, ele está somando "junto", se eu digito 2 na primeira vez fica 2 (certo), mas se eu digito 2 de novo, fica 4 o resultado.. acho que o problema esta nesse for ai dentro do do while, mas não teria como tirar ele dai, ou teria?

Comment: Coloque o `fat=1;` logo após a leitura do número, antes do loop de cálculo do fatorial.

Comment: Eu não tinha me tocado da variável global, não é uma boa pratica encher o código de variaveis globais (mas esse não é o assunto), eu atualizei o código colocando tua variaveis (exerto o resp) dentro do loop

Comment: Ah, não sabia desse esquema das variáveis, sempre achei que era necessário colocar elas lá em cima antes de começar a desenvolver o algoritmo em si, vai ser útil nos próximos exercícios, muito obrigado!

Comment: Recomento ler esse artigo: https://www.embarcados.com.br/por-que-evitar-variaveis-globais/